# Display SQL View as HTML table with SelectList default value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm displaying an SQL Server view *vw_FormattedData* in a HTML table. I am trying to update the column *superUserLevel* with a value based on user input. (A HTML Select input)

Basically I am trying to set the selected value of the HTML selectbox (SelectList) to whatever is in my View.

Is there a way in my Index.chtml loop to pass @item.superUserLevel into this? I may be going about this in completely the wrong way. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

**HomeController.cs**

```
namespace FormPostTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private DannyContext db = new DannyContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["OurData"] = db.vw_FormattedData.ToList();

            var queryLevels = from a in db.Level select a;
            ViewData["Levels"] = new SelectList(queryLevels, "id", "levelDescription", "DONT KNOW WHICH IS SELECTED FROM HERE");

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.chtml**

```
@model FormPostTest.Models.vw_FormattedData

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row top-buffer">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-striped top-buffer">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Forename
                </th>
                <th>
                    Surname
                </th>
                <th>
                    Line1
                </th>
                <th>
                    Line2
                </th>
                <th>
                    City
                </th>
                <th>
                    Country
                </th>
                <th>
                    Super User Level
                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in @ViewData["OurData"] as List<FormPostTest.Models.vw_FormattedData>)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.forename
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.surname
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.line1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.line2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.city
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.country
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownList("Levels", null, "** Please Select **", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SQL**

```
create table person(
  id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
  forename varchar(50) not null,
  surname varchar(50) not null
);

insert into person (forename, surname) values ('Arsene', 'Wenger');
insert into person (forename, surname) values ('Nigel', 'Pearson');

create table address(
  id int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
  line1 varchar(50),
  line2 varchar(50),
  city varchar(50),
  country varchar(50),
  personId int not null
);

insert into address (line1, line2, city, country, personId) values ('Emirates Stadium', '75 Drayton Park', 'London', 'England', 1);
insert into address (line1, line2, city, country, personId) values ('King Power Stadium', 'Filbert Way', 'Leicester', 'England', 2);

create table superuser(
  id int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
  personId int not null,
  permissionLevel int
);

create view vw_FormattedData as
select
  p.forename,
  p.surname,
  a.line1,
  a.line2,
  a.city,
  a.country,
  su.permissionLevel as superUserLevel
from
  person p
left join
  address a
  on a.personId = p.id
left join
  superuser su
  on su.personId = p.id;

create table levels(
  id int not null primary key,
  levelDescription varchar(50)
);

insert into levels (id, levelDescription) values (1, 'One');
insert into levels (id, levelDescription) values (2, 'Two');
insert into levels (id, levelDescription) values (3, 'Three');
```

Comment: You can use ajax to send back the new values, try with [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) and see also [knockoutmvc](http://knockoutmvc.com/)

Comment: I'm not having a problem sending the values back. It's trying to populate the dropdown box with values that are already in the view that is the problem.

Comment: When and how you know the selected value ? However if you know the value on client side you can use jQuery to select value on dropdown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not using `DropDownList` correctly and none of this will post back correctly anyway (all the dropdowns have the same id and name attributes).

View model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public IList<vw_FormattedData> Data { get; set; }
  public SelectList Levels { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
  model.Data = db.vw_FormattedData.ToList();
  var queryLevels = from a in db.Level select a;
  model.Levels = new SelectList(queryLevels, "id", "levelDescription");
  return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model YourAssembly.MyViewModel
....
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Data.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@Model.Data[i].forename</td>
    ....
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Data[i].superUserLevel, Model.Levels)</td>
  </tr>
```

This will create a select with the options defined by  `SelectList Levels` and will bind to the value of `vw_FormattedData.superUserLevel` (you have not included your model definition so I'm just assuming the property is named `superUserLevel`). So if you have 3 options with values 1, 2 and 3, and the value of `superUserLevel` is 2, then the second option will be selected by default.

**Edit**

Turns out `DropDownListFor()` does not work correctly in loops. The workaround is to use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Data[i].superUserLevel, new SelectList(Model.Levels, "id", "levelDescription", Model.Data[i].superUserLevel))
```

and the view model property needs to changed to

```
public IEnumerable<Level> Levels { get; set; }
```

and in the controller

```
var queryLevels = from a in db.Level select a;
model.Levels = queryLevels;
```

Comment: I am getting a compile error on @Html.DropDownListFor(Model.Data[i].superUserLevel, Model.Levels)


The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Is `superUserLevel` type of `int`? or is it a complex property?

Comment: public int? superUserLevel { get; set; }

Comment: That part is correct. Are you sure the `SelectList` is correct? - the error seems to suggest its not

Comment: I just iterated through model.Levels in my controller using Debug.WriteLine() and it prints 1, 2, 3

Comment: also should Model.Data[i].forename be @Model.Data[i].forename. Is there something I can put in place of @Html.DropDownListFor(Model.Data[i].superUserLevel, Model.Levels) to make it just compile?

Comment: Yes it should be @Model.Data[i].forename.

Comment: @DannyCullen, Sorry, but it should be @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Data[i].superUserLevel, Model.Levels)

Comment: That now compiles, but the select box defaults to the first value (1, "One"), even though the actual value is (3, "Three"). The difference can be seen by using the following: 
<td class="superUserLevel">
@Model.Data[i].superUserLevel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Data[i].superUserLevel, Model.Levels, new { @class = "form-control" })
</td>

Comment: If the value of `Model.Data[0].superUserLevel` is 3, then the 3rd option (the one with value=3) should be selected. Using your html above is `@Model.Data[i].superUserLevel` displaying `3` (i.e. just an integer)?

Comment: Yes its displaying the number 3 then above the select box, but displaying (1, "One") in the select box which is I am assuming the default. It's as if it doesn't read anything from m => m.Data[i].superUserLevel

Comment: Just found out from a few SO posts that there is a bug with `DropDownListFor()` when working with collections. I'll update answer with a workaround shortly.

Comment: I changed one of the lines in your solution to m => m.Data[i].superUserLevel and it works!

Comment: Doh - I did it again!